# How to find privilege for attributes comes from SDK.Metadata.RetrieveEntity in dynamics crm?

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a list of attribute comes through SDK.Metadata.RetrieveEntity.And i want to know the privilege for each.I found IsValidForCreate and CanBeSecuredForCreate So i am confused.Likewise I want to know that it has update read and create privilege or not.

```
SDK.Metadata.RetrieveEntity(SDK.Metadata.EntityFilters.Attributes,
                "contact",
                null,
                false,
                function (entityMetadata) { successRetrieveEntity(entityMetadata); },
                errorRetrieveEntity);
function successRetrieveEntity(entityMetadata)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < entityMetadata.Attributes.length; i++) {
        //how to get privilege?
    }
}
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? All entities share basically the same set of privileges: create, read, write, delete, append, appendto, share and assign (and evt. reparent). (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309366.aspx) Perhaps you need to know the privileges a user has regarding a specific entity record?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Find Privileges for Attributes/Fields

Kindly refer this [link](https://lakshmanindian.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/field-level-security-user-privileges-for-a-particular-attribute-using-javascript-in-crm-2011-crm-2013/)